# INSERT into table with foreign key - PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, foreign-keys

I have one database called "Profiles".
This database contains two tables called "users" and "profiles":

**Users:**
user_id
name
email
password

**Profiles:**
profile_id
first_name
last_name
summary

I am working on a CRUD scenario using PHP and PDO. Currently, I'm trying to "add" (create) a new profile entry. The assignment states: "Make sure to mark the entry with the foreign key **user_id** of the currently logged in user. (create)".

I don't understand how to connect the two tables together in PDO. I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity       constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`profiles`.`profile`, CONSTRAINT `profile_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in /websites-mamp/asmt-profile/add.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /websites-mamp/asmt-profile/add.php(32): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /websites-mamp/asmt-profile/add.php on line 32

Also, what does `CONSTRAINT profile_ibfk_2` mean?

My code is:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "pdo.php";

// Validate field entries
if ( isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['summary'])) {


    $sql = "INSERT INTO profile (first_name, last_name, summary)
               VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :summary)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        ':summary' => $_POST['summary']
        ));
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Record added";
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">

    <form method="post">
        <p>First Name:
        <input type="text" name="first_name" /></p>
        <p>Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="last_name" /></p>
        <p>Summary:
        <textarea type="text" name="summary"></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
        <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Cancel">
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where in the code do I connect to the foreign key? I've tried WHERE clauses, but that isn't helping. Can someone explain this easily? I've been exploring StackOverflow here for similar issues, but most of it is above my head or it's not PDO. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: INSERT does not allow a where clause. TO fix this, just add the foreign key the same way you add the others.

Comment: @MariaGosur I think you should have to use Stored Procedure.

Comment: @user3441151 Why would the OP have to use Stored Procedures?

Comment: @Akin Can you elaborate on adding the foreign key the same way you add the others? I'm not quite understanding..

Answer (score 0):

`profile_ibfk_2` is the name of the foreign key. You're trying to adf a row into your `profile` table, but you do not set the `user_id` too. So change your `INSERT` statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO profile (first_name, last_name, summary, user_id)
           VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :summary, :user_id)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    ':summary' => $_POST['summary'],
    ':user_id' => $whatEverToGetTheCurrentUserID,
    ));
```

Comment: Does $whatEverToGetTheCurrentUserID also turn into $_POST['user_id'];? I don't understand what the $variable would be?

Comment: This variable contains ID of the user. It depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is if you have session stored variable for user_id
since you have session_start in your code, place this into your login.php file or whatever filename you have before the user enters your homepage, first you need to select your user_id given you logged in from a login interface

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username = :user,password = :password";
$stmnt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmnt->execute(array(':user'=>$user,':password'=>$password));
$data = $stmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userid = $data['id'];
```

then store your userid into session like this:

```
$_SESSION['currentid'] = $userid;
```

then add the userid into your insert statement:

```
$id = $_SESSION['currentid'];

if ( isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['summary'])) {


    $sql = "INSERT INTO profile (first_name, last_name, summary,userid)
               VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :summary,:userid)";
    $stmnt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->execute(array(
        ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        ':summary' => $_POST['summary'],
        ':userid' => $id;
        ));
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Record added";
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
}
```

you must have a foreign key in your child table Profiles which is linked into the parent table Users in order to prevent integrity violation of your tables using foreign keys, assuming you have session_start also in your login.php file or whatever the filename is.
Or if you don't have login interface, just search for userid of the user you want to insert the profile using select and stored it into any variable, you could also store it into an input tag like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

just make sure to include the input tag inside your form to be included